# in css if i set a background image to repeat will it be downloaded once ?

Tags: html, css, download, bandwidth

i have a div which is ex. 500px by 500px and i have an image (texture image) that is 10px by 10px. i have set this image to repeat horizontally and vertically. i have done this in order to save bandwidth but the question is : does this save bandwidth or it is the same as i make a background image 500 by 500 px ??? (so this image will be downloaded once to the client or it will be downloaded as many times as it is repeated ?? )

the same question for two img tag in html that have the same src but different sizes .

thanks in advice !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will only be downloaded once.  Even if you load the image separately on the page (perhaps in an `img` tag) it will only be downloaded once (by any good browser, anyway).

It is entirely up to the browser how the downloading of the background image is handled.  The browser has to see the image url in the CSS rule, actively download the image (however many times it wants to, hopefully once) and render it according to how it wants to use your rules.